# Accidentally deleted production Postgres DB in Heroku dashboard

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have been trying to get a staging server working on Heroku where my product app runs. I thought the issue was related to a mis-configured database. There seemed to be some odd things visible in the Heroku dashboard where it showed multiple instances of Postgresql add-ons, with different names. On the production implementation of the database, it said it was also attached to my staging app - which did not seem right - so I deleted that (I want my staging app to have a clean DB and not be attached to production).

BUT... now it appears my production database is GONE. I have a support ticket in to Heroku. But would LOVE some help - I am pretty desperate at this point!

I have gone into the Activity menu for my Heroku app and rolled back to a point before the screwup - but I am pretty sure that just restores code & settings. So I am still dead as the database is not there.

To make matters worse, I quickly checked pg:backups and the list it returns is quite old. That doesn't seem right - I think I should have automatic backups - so that adds to the fear that I may have royally screwed this up.

I expected the database to detach from my staging app but remain intact for my production app. Now all that is showing is the "old" version of the database.

UPDATE: I was able to promote an instance of an older database that was still attached to my app, so the app itself is up and running (but with older data). Still waiting on Heroku support to respond to my trouble ticket and hopefully help me restore this database.

RESOLUTION: Heroku tech support responded overnight and was able to recover/restore my production database as hoped, so only minor damage done with users unable to access recent data for about 6 hours. So 2 learnings from this.

First, and fairly obvious, is to be very careful with how you manage your production DB and make sure you have regularly scheduled backups occuring (I thought I did, but after an automatic Postgres upgrade it appears those went away and I did not know to re-schedule them).

Second, that Heroku does continuously backup your app/data and can help you recover from this kind of disaster as long as you are on one of their paid plans. But you have to contact them through tech support and request this, there is no way to recover from these automatic backups via the dashboard or CLI.

Comment: Unless you have a backup (and it sounds like you don't have a recent one) I think you're out of luck. In the future, you can use [`heroku addons:detach`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-addons-detach-attachment_name) to detach a database from an app without destroying it.

Comment: I was hoping Heroku would have a safety mechanism to bail me out. I also believed that I was getting automatic daily backups (I am on a paid plan). Good to know about the addons:detach command.

Comment: Well, when I say "out of luck" I mean "out of luck as far as what you can do, and what we can recommend". Your support ticket may have better results.